# translate data dynamically react localize redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have gone through the docs for react localize redux - https://ryandrewjohnson.github.io/react-localize-redux-docs/

I have managed to get a simple example working but I can't figure out how to use it with the json data structure that would be useful to me instead of the example structure they use as an example.

For instance I would like to have "reviews" as an array so I can use the same key id's, but when doing that I get `missing translation id` error and this makes it difficult to filter the data in a way that I want to, for instance I want to be able map through `sub` but having to name the subItems `cat1`, `cat2` etc so they can be used in the translation component limits the ability to do this

How can I change the data structure to make it more useful and allow me to map through it?

**Main.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from 'react-dom/server'
import { withLocalize } from 'react-localize-redux'
import globalTranslations from '../translations/global.json'
import { Translate } from "react-localize-redux";
import styled from 'styled-components'
import translations from '../translations/global.json';

const Wrap = styled.div`
  margin: 100px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;

`
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      reviews: ['cat1', 'cat2'],
    };

    this.props.addTranslation(translations);

    this.props.initialize({
      languages: [
        { name: "English", code: "en" },
        { name: "French", code: "fr" }
      ],
      translation: globalTranslations,
      options: { renderToStaticMarkup }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Wrap>
          <Translate>
          {({translate}) =>
            this.state.reviews.map((review, index) =>
              <div key={index}>
                <h2>{ translate(`reviews.${review}.cat`) }</h2>
                <p>{ translate(`reviews.${review}.desc`) }</p>
              </div>
            )
          }
        </Translate>

        <Translate>
          {({translate}) =>
            this.state.reviews.filter(items => 'cat1').map((review, index) =>
              <div key={index}>
                <h2>{ translate(`reviews.${review}.sub.cat`) }</h2>
                <p>{ translate(`reviews.${review}.desc`) }</p>
              </div>
            )
          }
        </Translate>
      </Wrap>
    )
  }
}

export default withLocalize(Main);
```

**global.json**

```
{
  "reviews": {
    "cat1": {
      "cat": ["food and drink", "french food and drink" ],
      "slug": "food-and-drink",
      "desc": ["english", "french"],
      "sub": {
        "cat1": {
          "name": "food 1"
        },
        "cat2": {
          "name": "food 2"
        }
      }
    },
    "cat2": {
      "cat": ["review2" , "french review 2"],
      "slug": "food-and-drink",
      "desc": ["english", "french"],
      "sub": {
        "cat1": {
          "name": "food 1"
        },
        "cat2": {
          "name": "food 2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```